# Image Absolute source path with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

This code gives something like `../movies/1.png`, the exact src attribute:

```
$("img").attr("src");
```

**How do I get absolute path of an image with jQuery?**

I want to get something like `http://site.com/movies/1.png`, not `../movies/1.png`

Comment: Check out this post http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2009/10/02/convert-a-relative-path-to-absolute-path-with-jquery-and.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can easily be done by accessing the `.src` property directly on the `<img>`:

```
$('img')[0].src;
```

**example**: http://jsfiddle.net/9mKz2/

(<sup>I didn't test it on all browser right now</sup>)