# Is there a jquery Regex equivalent and how to use it?

Tags: jquery, regex

Basically there's an img src that I'm retrieving via DOM and it looks like this

```
<img title="SAC PICOTIN HERMES" alt="SAC PICOTIN HERMES" id="bigpic" width="300" height="300" style="display: inline-block;" src="../198-thickbox/sac-picotin-hermes-beige-vintage.jpg">
```

As you can see from the src it's not a full URL. I need to find a method which would remove the two .. before the first backslash so I can append the full URL of the folder.

My current code is:

```
var image = $('#window').contents().find('#primary_block #image-block img').attr('src');
var imageCheck =/../g;
var imageURL = image.replace(DO SOME REGEX HERE)
```

How do I replace and remove the two .. from the URL?

Thanks

Comment: `var imageURL = image.substring( 2 );`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get image src with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952173/get-image-src-with-jquery) or [Image Absolute source path with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6181366/1048572)

Comment: You should use just `$('#image-block img').prop('src')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
var imageURL = image.replace(/^\.\./, '')
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, perfect answer. I'll accept it in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

If there are always two leading periods:

```
var imageURL = 'http://full-url-here' + image.substr(2);
```

Otherwise:

```
var imageURL = image.src.replace(/^\.*/, 'http://full-url-here');
```